# Changing a form to responsive and positioning it

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm new here so apologies in advance i will hopefully not break any rules. I was hoping for some assistance with the position of and domain search form on my webpage and also a method to make it responsive if posible as at present the Submit button will move underneath the text entry if the page is too small and gets further away from the input if the page is too large. I'm new at css (apart from changing colours etc) so any advice would be most appreciated.

I have positioned the form at present using:

```
.dm-reg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  z-index: 10;

}
```

Will this ensure that the screen size will not affect the position of the form? I have used jsfiddle and altered sizes and it seems to stay put, however if ppossible i would like it centered horizontally at all times, so without using left:20% is that possible?

I have set up a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dtorr1981/vp0zwxsu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vp0zwxsu/1/

The trick is to make your wrapper wrapper with 100% and then center the form within that wrapper using `margin: auto;`

```
.dm-reg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
form {
    width: 65%;
    margin: auto !important;
}
```

**Note:** I included `!important` on my form margin because it was being overwritten by normalize.css in that jsfiddle, and I wanted to avoid changed your HTML if possible; however, a better way to do this would be to give the form an id and refer to it by id in the CSS.

Comment: Ahh Thank you :) Do you have any additional advice for the resizing issue with the submit button by any chance? If you stretch or shrink the jsfiddle output window you will see that the button moves. Am i right in assuming that this is due to the form not being responsive?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  You may want to consider using a fixed width instead of a % width for the form actually, and then display it differently when your screen becomes narrower than 800. That's how I would do it anyway.

Comment: By the way, if this solution was helpful to you, would you mind marking my answer as accepted?  That keeps the question from remaining open-ended. i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png